# Perl directories, file sort, print list with size and date

Tags: perl, file, sorting

My task is:

1. Read the directory, type of sorting, and order of sorting from command line.
2. Sort the file names and print them out with size and date.

Here is what I got so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
my $dir = "";
my $sortby = "";
my $order = "";
my $result;

$result = GetOptions (
                    'dir=s'  => \$dir,                # specify derictory
                   'sortby=s'    =>  \$sortby,        # 'name' or 'date'
                   'order=s'     =>  \$order);        # 'asc'- or 'des'-ending order of sorting

print "derictory = $dir, sortby  = $sortby, order = $order \n\n";


opendir (DH, $dir)or die "couldn open dericroty: $!\n";
my @filenames = grep ! /^\./, readdir DH;
closedir (DH);

if ($sortby eq "name") {

     if ($order eq "asc") {
         foreach my $name (sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} @filenames) {
         my @statinfo = stat("$dir/$name");
         print "$name\tsize= " . $statinfo[7] . ",\t last modified=" . 
         scalar(localtime($statinfo[9])) . "\n";
         }
     }
     elsif ($order eq "des") {
         foreach my $name (sort {lc $b cmp lc $a} @filenames) {
         my @statinfo = stat("$dir/$name");
         print "$name\tsize= " . $statinfo[7] . ",\t last modified=" . 
         scalar(localtime($statinfo[9])) . "\n";
         }
     }      
}


if ($sortby eq "date") {
    if ($order eq "asc") {
        @filenames = sort { -M "$dir/$a" <=> -M "$dir/$b" } (@filenames);   
        print  join ("\n", @filenames);
    }    
    elsif ($order eq "des") {
        @filenames = sort { -M "$dir/$b" <=> -M "$dir/$a" } (@filenames);   
        print  join ("\n", @filenames);
    }    
}
```

The problem is if I need to sort it by date modified, I don't know how to print out the list of the file names with the size and date. I guess I am supposed to use the stat function, but I can't loop through names, and get each stat.
All I have above is basically what I was able to google and put together.

Comment: You say " i cant loop through names, and get the each stat."  Why can't you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different way to think about the problem. The essential points:

1. Write **small functions that do simple things**, and build your program
   by assembling those functions together.
2. If you collect all of your information in a **convenient data
   structure** (in this example, a list of hashes), the algorithmic/logical
   aspects of the program become easy and natural.

For simplicity, this example ignore option-parsing and instead just accepts the params as regular command line arguments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub main {
    my ($dir, $sortby, $order) = @ARGV;

    my @contents = read_dir($dir);
    my $sb       = $sortby eq 'date' ? 'mtime' : 'path';
    my @sorted   = sort { $a->{$sb} cmp $b->{$sb}  } @contents;
    @sorted      = reverse(@sorted) if $order eq 'des';

    for my $fi (@sorted){
        print $fi->{path}, ' : ', $fi->{mtime}, "\n";
    }
}

sub read_dir {
    # Takes a dir path.
    # Returns a list of file_info() hash refs.
    my $d = shift;
    opendir(my $dh, $d) or die $!;
    return map  { file_info($_) }  # Collect info.
           map  { "$d/$_" }        # Attach dir path.
           grep { ! /^\.\.?$/ }    # No dot dirs.
           readdir($dh);
}

sub file_info {
    # Takes a path to a file/dir.
    # Returns hash ref containing the path plus any stat() info you need.
    my $f = shift;
    my @s = stat($f);
    return {
        path  => $f,
        mtime => $s[9],
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line? i dont know what qwestion mark means.  my $sb       = $sortby eq 'date' ? 'mtime' : 'path';

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to sort by certain properties of your data, you may want to take a look at the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).  This is a basic example of how you might use it to sort by modified time:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant MTIME_STAT_INDEX => 9;
use constant FILENAME_INDEX => 0;
use constant MTIME_INDEX => 1;

# Grab a list of files in the current folder
my $some_dir = '.';
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";
my @fileNames = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

# Use a Schwartzian transform to generate a sorted list of <file_name, mtime> tuples 
my @sortedByMtime = 
    map { $_ }
    sort { $a->[MTIME_INDEX] cmp $b->[MTIME_INDEX] } 
    map { [$_, (stat($_))[MTIME_STAT_INDEX]] } @fileNames;

# Print the file name and mtime
for my $sortedRecord (@sortedByMtime) {
    print $sortedRecord->[FILENAME_INDEX] . "\t" . $sortedRecord->[MTIME_INDEX] . "\n";
}

1;
```

It may help to read the transform outside-in (ie starting at the end and working toward the start).  Starting with a list of file names, you use map to produce an array containing entries of the form `<file_name, modified_time>`.  You then sort this list by modified time and can use the final map (ie the first one) to strip out any unwanted properties.  In this example, I did not strip anything out, but I hope you get the idea that you could in theory have other properties in this built up structure, such as file size, for instance.

This is intended to just get you started as a proof of concept – I did not take much consideration for efficiency, error handling, or making the output pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html). This module (which comes with Subversion allows you to easily access all sorts of information about the file.

You should also look at [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). This module allows you to easily format your date and time.

I would also not worry about having four separate sorting routines. Instead, just sort what you need in an array standard ascending order. Then, before you print out, see if the user requested descending order. If the user did request descending order, you can use the [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) to reverse your sorted array.

I am using [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). The array I am storing my file names contains not a string, but a *reference* to a hash. This way, each entry in my array contains four separate bits of information about my file.

I am also use Pod::Usage to print out messages based upon my [POD documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html). POD is a rather simple format for storing documentation about your program. Users can use the `perldoc` command to display the pod:

```
$ perldoc prog.pl
```

Or, they can use commands such as `pod2html` to convert the documentation into HTML. These various Perldoc and POD commands come with your Perl distribution. I highly recommend that you learn POD and use it extensively. It keeps your program documentation in your program and allows you to produce all sorts of formats for your documentation. (Text, HTML, manpage, markdown, wiki, etc.).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

# All of these are standard Perl module and come with all distributions
# or Perl

use Time::Piece;
use File::stat;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;
use File::Basename;

my ( $directory, $sort_order, $sort_descending, $help );

#
# Using pod2usage to print out my messages
#
GetOptions (
    "directory=s"   => \$directory,
    "sort=s"        => \$sort_order,
    "descending"    => \$sort_descending,
    "help"          => \$help,
) or pod2usage;

if ( $help ) {
    pod2usage ( -message => qq(Use command 'perldoc print_dir.pl' for complete documetation) );
}

if ( not ( defined $directory and defined $sort_order ) ) {
    pod2usage ( -message => qq(Must use parameters "directory" and "sort") );
}

if ( $sort_order ne "name"  and
     $sort_order ne "ctime" and
     $sort_order ne "size"  and
     $sort_order ne "mtime" ) {
     die qq(Sort order must be "name", "size", "ctime", or "mtime"\n);
 }

opendir ( my $dir_fh, $directory );         #Will autodie here if directory doesn't exist

my @files;
while ( my $file = readdir $dir_fh ) {
    $file = "$directory/$file";
    next if not -f $file;

    #
    # Note I'm using File::stat to get the info on the files
    #

    my $stat = stat $file or die qq(Couldn't stat file "$file"\n);
    my %file;
    $file{NAME}  = basename $file;
    $file{CTIME} = $stat->ctime;
    $file{MTIME} = $stat->mtime;
    $file{SIZE}  = $stat->size;
    #
    # I'm storing this information in a hash and pushing a Hash Reference
    #
    push @files, \%file;    #Pushing a reference to the hash
}
closedir $dir_fh;

my @sorted_files =  sort file_sort @files;

#
# I am using the fact that my hash keys and my sort options
# are very similar. One routine sorts all which ways
#
sub file_sort {
    my $sort_by = uc $sort_order;
    if ( $sort_order eq "name" ) {
        return $a->{$sort_by} cmp $b->{$sort_by};
    } else {
        return $a->{$sort_by} <=> $b->{$sort_by};
    }
}

#
# If the user wants descending order, reverse the array
#
if ( $sort_descending ) {
    @sorted_files = reverse @sorted_files;
}

#
# I'm using 'printf' to print out a nice report.
# My $format is the format of the report, and I
# can use it for the title or the body.
#
my $format = "%-20.20s  %-10d  %-11.11s  %-11.11s\n";
( my $title_format = $format ) =~ s/d/s/;
printf $title_format, "Name", "Sixe", "Mod-Time", "C-Time";
say join "  ", "=" x 20, "=" x 10, "=" x 11, "=" x 11;
for my $file ( @sorted_files ) {
    #
    # The "->" dereferences the hash
    # Note how I use Time::Piece to format my time
    #
    my $mtime = Time::Piece->new ( $file->{MTIME} );
    my $ctime = Time::Piece->new ( $file->{CTIME} );
    printf $format, $file->{NAME}, $file->{SIZE}, $mtime->ymd, $ctime->ymd;
}

#
# Here be the Plain Old Documention (POD) This is the standard
# way to document Perl programs. You can use the "perldoc" program
# to print it out, and pod2usage to print out bits and pieces.
#

=pod

=head1 NAME

print_dir.pl

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    print_dir.pl -sort [name|size|mtime|ctime] -directory $directory [ -descending ]

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This program does somee amazing wonderful stuff...

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item *

-sort

(Required) Sort order of directory parameters can be C<name>, C<size>, C<mtime>, C<ctime>

=item *

-directory

(Required) Name of the directory to print

=item *

-descending

(Optional) Sort in descending order instead of ascending order

=back

=cut
```