# Filter file in folder according to its modified date

Tags: perl

There is folder which contains a lots of file. I want to pick the file which are create or modified today in Perl. I don't want to loop through the all file in the folder.
For example, I have 50 files in a folder, out them 10 files are added today, than I want to pick only 10 file that are added today in the folder.

Any help will be great for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284208/perl-directories-file-sort-print-list-with-size-and-date

Comment: Creation date is commonly unavailable on unix; it's simply not stored anywhere.

Comment: File::Find::Rule makes this easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have create time - Unix doesn't track it.

You can have modification time (or `ctime` which is "change time").

But you can't do this without looping through all the files - because at the very least, you need to `stat` them to check their attributes.

If you need recursion - `File::Find::Rule` is the tool for the job (as Ikegami suggests in the comments).

If you don't, then as simple as the [`-M`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) test (or [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html))

```
foreach my $file ( glob "/path/*.ext" ) { 
    next unless (stat($file))[9] < time() - 84600; 
}
```

Or:

```
next unless -M $file > 1;
```

Or you could apply `grep` to filter your `glob`:

```
foreach my $file ( grep { -M < 1 } glob "/path/to/*.ext" ) {
```

But be under no illusions - in each case, there is a loop to test every file, and perform a `stat` to check it's age.